# Draggable Element Event Listeners (JS / React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, addeventlistener, event-listener, removeeventlistener

For example, if i have a draggable list of divs and I wanna manipulate classes on dragStart, dragEnd, dragOver etc. how should my event listeners look like and how and where do I remove them.

this is the div element:

```
<StyledDragableContainer
              id="draggable"
              draggable
              onDragStart={(e) => dragItem.current = index}
              onDragEnter={(e) => dragOverItem.current = index}
              onDragEnd={handleSort}
 >
     <h3>label</h3>
     <input type="checkbox/>
```

and these are event listeners I have so far:

```
window.onload = function (){

    const source = document.getElementById("draggable");

    let target

    source.addEventListener("dragover", (event) => {
      target = event.target;
      target.classList.add("dragging");
    });

    source.addEventListener("dragend", (event) => {
      target = event.target;
      if(target.classList.contains("dragging")) target.classList.remove("dragging");
    });
  }
```

Never manipulated with event listeners and wanted to give it a shot. It adds the classname but it doesn't work properly as intended, so if anyone can take a look and guide me on how to manipulate classes via event listeners on draggable div I would really appreciate it.

I was thinking of opacity 0.5 when dragging, i achieved this with active classname on the div, now I 'd like background colour change on dragOver / dragEnter just see it in work and remove classnames on dragEnd and also remove event listeners as intended.